# Keno UI Grid With Angular and Batch Editing Issues

Tags: angularjs, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-grid

I have a grid that is filled with data from the server when the controller is being initialized and the grid allow batch editing and i have a custom delete command that will mark the dataItem as **MarkedAsDeleted**. My requirements is:-

1. If i update any row in the grid, the corresponding item in the angular dataSource didn't get updated. How to do this??
2. If the user click the custom delete command , i want to mark the item to be MarkAsDeleted but i want that item to be hidden from the grid but still exists in the data source.
3. I want to handle changes in the grid, so i can mark the corresponding item to be updated for example.

This is my code:-

```
                        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                        data: this.jobCategory.minorCategories,
                        batch: true,
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                id: "id",
                                fields: {
                                    id: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                    name: { type: "string", validation: { required: true, pattern: '.{3,200}' } },
                                    notes: { type: "string" }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    this.gridOptions = {
                        toolbar: [{ name: "create", text: "Add a new minor category" }],
                        dataSource: dataSource,
                        autoBind: true,
                        height: 300,
                        editable: true,
                        sortable: true,
                        columns: [
                            {
                                field: "name",
                                title: "Name"
                            }, {
                                field: "notes",
                                title: "Notes"
                            },
                            {
                                command: [
                                    {
                                        text: "",
                                        template: '<span class="k-button-icontext" ng-click="vm.test(dataItem)">Delete</span>'
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    };

test(dataItem): void {
        dataItem.markAsDeleted = true;
    }
```

and this is my html

```
<div kendo-grid="minorCategoriesGrid" k-options="vm.gridOptions">
                        </div>
```

Comment: any help for this issue

Answer (score 0):

Bulk edit is currently not available for Kendo UI grid (Angular 2).  I'm hoping that it will be available with the major release that has been announce for January 18th.